# Redirect http to https by configuring .conf file of apache

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, https, proxy

I have configure apache to tomcat configuration by code like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName captiveportal
ProxyPass       / http://ip:port/path
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip:port/path
</VirtualHost>
```

Now i want to reirect this request to https 
How can i achieve this ?

After looking your answer i have changes my configuration like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/crt1.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/key1.key"
ProxyPass       / http://ip:port/path
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName captiveportal
Redirect / https://ip:port/path
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i type `captiveportal` on my browser it redirects me on url `https://ip:port/path` and it displays `problem loading page`

One more thing i don't want to display `https://ip:port/path` on browser.

Note :- `https://ip:port/path`  where port is my tomcat port and ip is machine ip where tomcat run.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName captiveportal
   Redirect / https://my.host.name/
</VirtualHost>
```

...and then put your `ProxyPass` directives in side your SSL `VirtualHost` block instead.

Comment: Please check edited question as i have made changes suggested by u and face other problem.

Comment: You should probably be redirecting to `https://captiveportal/`, which is what I was trying to suggest here.