# How to proxy http to https using Apache httpd (v2.2)

Tags: apache, google-maps

I'm trying to set up a [simple proxypass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) in [Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/) that will proxy certain requests. Here is what I have tried, but it doesnt seem to like the change from http to https?

```
ProxyPass /maps https://maps.googleapis.com/maps
```

Perhaps I am missing an extra step?

I have read a little about setting up certificates but this seems to be long winded for such a simple task?

The result I get currently is a 500 error.

Comment: I would like this question to be considered for reopen please. It was originally asked so that I could get help setting up Apache to work with Google places API within a website. I think that it relates to the following criteria: 1) specific programming problem;
2) software tools commonly used by programmers; 3) practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development. Even a simple explanation as to where I may have gone off topic so that I could make changes would be good, thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: @Kev can you please respond to my comments so that I may improve my question and get this reopened. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest turning this question into a general one: howto proxy http using Apache

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ok after reading many solutions that involved setting up certificates, and virtual hosts etc etc. I finally found a basic config that does not require any of that.

Here is what I have used to access proxy autocomplete google places requests through local host on an installation of Apache including ssl support ([version 2.2 for windows](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/)).

Edit the apache file httpd.conf

turn on the required modules...

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

go to the bottom of the file and add the following configuration for mod_proxy...

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /maps https://maps.googleapis.com/maps
ProxyPassReverse /maps https://maps.googleapis.com/maps

</IfModule>
```

Thats it, the rest was all default configuration settings from when I installed Apache.

Further configuration details relating to apache proxy can be found at the [Apache mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

General Apache [docs for version 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).

Comment: This is what worked for me: http://serverfault.com/questions/659486/setting-up-basic-proxy-from-https-to-http-via-apache

Comment: SSLProxyEngine on - makes all magic here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a redirect to https first and do a proxypass from that virtual host then. Also see: [Redirect http to https apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335329/redirect-http-to-https-by-configuring-conf-file-of-apache)

Comment: Thanks for your input but after some digging, I didn't need to do the redirect.

Comment: you didn't understand our needs: we need to see https resources through http