# Why won't my proxy work with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: apache, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway endpoint and I want to be able to access it from my webpage; the api gateway will response with a string.

I would like to make an ajax request to the endpoint then use the response of that to do my work on the ui.

So in my proxy.conf file, I added:

```
ProxyPass /proxyme https://API_ENDPOINT
ProxyPassReverse /proxyme https://API_ENDPOINT
```

When I execute:

```
$.get("API_ENDPOINT")
```

I get a 404. Am I missing something to make this proxy work? I'm sure that I restarted my apache when I added the proxy.

Please let me know if additional detail is needed.

Edit:

Does it matter if my site is http and gateway is https?

Edit 2:

My object is to have my frontend js code hit some url:

```
/proxyme
```

and it should hit the api endpoint via a proxy:

```
https://API_ENDPOINT
```

once the data is received, my js will kick in and do rendering.

Comment: It looks like you need to redirect the http to https first. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130303/apache-config-how-to-proxypass-http-requests-to-https

Comment: no dice :( i set up apache on my localhost with mostly default settings then have proxy settings with those proxy pass...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP to HTTPS is a big no no and there's no way around it.