# Is there a way to force an application to post using https instead of http

Tags: apache, http, web, service, tcp

I have an application that sends a request to a web service. Unfortunately the application is compiled and the link to the web service is embedded in the application as http. (Yes I know how dumb that is, I didn't write it)

Recently, the 3rd party company is no longer allowing http requests, everything must be https.

The application runs as a webapp on Tomcat. The server is a windows server.

Is there a way to intercept the call to this web service and force it to use https?

Answer (score 1):

As you can't change the application's source code (as it is compiled), and you can't change the web service (as it is 3rd party) either, the only way to solve this problem is making **a proxy between the application and web service**. To do that, you need to (assume the proxy is running in localhost):

1. As the web service URL is embedded into the compiled application, in order to let application send HTTP request to our proxy, hosts mapping need to change (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) to override DNS. For example, if the HTTP request in application is `GET http://example.com/api/sample`, in `/etc/hosts`, `example.com` need to be mapped to `127.0.0.1`.
2. Make a proxy web server in localhost and open the same port as the web service. This proxy is a very simple web server (any backend programming tech can do it), it is only responsible for request-forwarding. In this way, when application send HTTP request  to `example.com`, it sends the request to the proxy server.
3. After receiving HTTP request from application, the proxy server extract the request URL/header/body and send HTTPS request to `example.com`'s real IP address. Please note: in this HTTPS request, a header `host` whose value is `example.com` should be added. 3rd party web service may check this header.
4. After the real response is returned from `example.com`, proxy will return it to the application.

Of course, you can also use **reverse engineering (Java Decompiler)** to get the application's "source code", change the web service URL and then compile again to a webapp. However, as the application may need to update/upgrade and it is may not under your control, this reverse engineering method is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy script. Write it in any server-side language you want, for example PHP, set the API URL to this script, the script does the https request for you and pass the results back to your app.

You could also use Apache itself as the proxy and use something like: [Apache config: how to proxypass http requests to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130303/apache-config-how-to-proxypass-http-requests-to-https)